# Eclipse Kepler Strange Compilation Error : Undefined method for the type

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, compiler-errors

I got a strange compilation error using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2. It keep saying that one of my method was undefined for the type of my class. The strange thing is, when I lookup the class, it has the method that the eclipse complain missing. Here is the screenshot: 
[image: Eclipse Strange Compilation Error]

Here is the interface of serviceNotification: 
[image: serviceNotification interface]

Does anyone have experience this strange compilation error? Any comment and suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Did you check is there any transitive dependencies are failing or project is not getting build completely. Check for the `Markers` or `Problems` tab, it will give you build path related issues. If you can resolve that first, you should be able to resolve this problem.

Comment: @CuriousMind : I have already check that there are no transitive dependencies or failing project that not getting build completely. All related project are build completely. I have post the detail that provided by eclipse in problems tab, and it still clear what to do to solve this.